# Can variables be eliminated here?

Tags: javascript

In this function from nczonline, I noticed that left and right are copied to i and j, but are never used after that.  Is there a way to eliminate either left and right or i and j?

```
function partition(items, left, right) {
    var pivot   = items[Math.floor((right + left) / 2)],
        i       = left,
        j       = right;
    while (i <= j) {
        while (items[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (items[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            swap(items, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: This looks like part of quicksort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply there so that it is shorter when used repetitively in the rest of the function.

Using `i` & `j` directly as the argument names is not descriptive enough, so he's assigning them to shorter variables within the function body.

Comment: @employee-0 - The correct answer is: yes. The right answer is: why would you?

Comment: variables are real places in memory that you take up as resources, they aren't made to be pretty descriptors.  never take more than you need, than from there you can be descriptive or comment the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can replace all instances of `i` with `left` and all instances of `j` with `right`.

But why would you want to do that?

Comment: or just replace the function parameters with i and j.

Comment: yes, you could do that – but that would make the function signature less descriptive

Comment: @Chronial That's what documentation is for.

Comment: @JosephSilber i and j are about as descriptive as left and right.

Comment: the author used two variables b.c. he was writing a tutorial, you would never do this in real production code.